# How difficult it is to get a TT in the U.S. after leaving the country?

Tags: research-process, tenure-track, visa

I completed my higher ed in the U.S. (from B.A. to Ph.D.) and have been in this country for 12 years. I received a TT offer from a teaching university ( I didn't enjoy it but appreciated the opportunity), but the visa thing didn't work out. At this point, I'll have to leave the country because I'm at the end of my OPT.

I received a job offer from my home country. The university itself is an English-teaching institute with a decent teaching load, and they are pushing for research. As far as I know, my future colleagues are most foreigners  (Korean, American, German, etc.). The pay is decent as well.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. is it still possible for me to get a TT position in the U.S. after leaving?
2. will my work experience outside the U.S. be counted/valued?

I have been interviewing at different universities, but my choices of the school were more out of desperation than what I wanted. The school that I loved most had to pause their search due to COVID, and I missed more than half of the applications because the former employer didn't inform me about the situation until March. After many hard and tearing days, I am wondering if I should take the job offer back home to continue doing what I do with much better support to do research. But I fear that I won't be back in the states after leaving here.

I'd be glad to know your experience or suggestions! Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be more strategic to get experience in a third country.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words!

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Is it possible to get a TT position in the US after leaving?

Yes, it is possible; I have done something similar (in Computer Science). I left the US to do an extended PostDoc and then returned to the US as a professor. This worked out for me in particular because I had experience and expertise in a specific area that the school was looking for. (And >40 publications by the time I returned.)

Q2. Will my work experience outside the US be counted/valued?

If you are productive there typically is no reason it won't. In particular, you need to continue to publish high quality work at top venues. This may be harder to do if you don't have good students. In this case you may look for good collaborators and do things like invite their students for research visits.

Comment: 'In this case ... good collaborators and do things... ' -> this is hard or near impossible to do unless you yourself do good work and/or belong to a top institution that students/collaborators see as a brand name, which they can then crow to future employers.

Comment: @ Prof. Santa Claus, yes, I have collaborators here from my school, which is a prestigious R1 institute. Since I'm still a recent grad, our relationships are still strong. But I do agree with what you said.

Comment: @ Nathan S. Thank you for your encouragement. The reason that has really made me question about the possibility is because I saw many people talk about how hard it is to even get an interview when they aren't here in the states. Not to mention that I don't have a H1B visa. But hey, thanks for sharing. I really am appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not whether you are in the US or outside the US. Frankly, nobody cares. There are many excellent universities outside the US (e.g., Cambridge University), and there are some horrible universities in the US (I won’t name examples), and obviously there are some excellent universities in the US and horrible universities in other countries. So if you apply for a tenure track position in the US, the idea that anyone will look at your CV and rule you out *just because you are living overseas* is ridiculous.

Now, they *might* rule you out or discount your experience because you are currently teaching at a bad or not-so-good university, whether it’s in the US or not. That’s the right question to be thinking about - how will the *specific university* you’re considering moving to affect your future US job prospects, not the country. But you haven’t told us very much about the university that gave you the job offer, so there is no way anyone here can assess what the effect will be. But anyway, that’s what you should focus your attention on. Academics move from places outside the US to tenure track positions in US universities all the time, so certainly as a question in the abstract, it can be done.

Comment: Dan, thank you for your detailed comments. The University I referred to is at a unique position in which they do have a high standard of accepting students. Still, they don't participate in national rankings due to it's a branch campus of Hong Kong Baptist University. There are only seven universities like this one in China that have been approved by the Ministry of Education. It's the first liberal arts college in China, and they are pushing for research more and more. Since I haven't started the position, so that's the best I know of.

Comment: @XSL thanks. Another relevant factor is what discipline you work in and whether the specific department you’ll be working at at that university is well-known within the discipline. Anyway, those are all important factors but at the end of the day good people can do good work anywhere, and it’s the work that you do that will have the largest effect on how your job applications are received.

Comment: @ Dan Romik. Thank you again for your kind words! I agreed with you, but I don't know how well-known the department is, to be frank with you. They do, however, have the ambition to get themself into the publishing game. The only thing I could think of is to keep up my scholarly work. I feel like that's what the committees will focus on if everything else being equal (like citizenship isn't a factor they use to eliminate the person).